# Powershell | Cannot create new user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script which will attempt to create a new active directory user.
However when I type the command I get the following error:

http://puu.sh/kHEFP/ab8a5b88c7.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should try typing out the error in your question rather than post an image.

Answer (score 0):

Puts single qoutes around the Path value, e.g.

```
-Path 'OU=Pupils,OU=School,DC=gap,DC=local'
```

See the docs for more information on the parameter usage:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617253.aspx

Comment: Now i get a new error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Aslimand' at line1: char:1

Comment: any thoughts on this one?

Comment: same problem, surround the whole name in quotes

Comment: i tried putting the first one in quotes "Borna Aslimand" and it still said line 1, char 1. Should the error char not change?